# Automatic comments in a C++ file

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

Since the start of the school year, I've been learning C++ as one of my electives. Since more than half of all the work we do is programming, our teacher makes us put this huge heading (all commented) at the top of each program and it's annoying to remember. Just to show you how long it really is:

```
    /*************************************
    Joe Michail
    Period 6
    C++ Computer Programming
    Teacher name
    High School Name
    Dev-C++
    Chapter , Page , Question 
    Name of program/Description
    x/xx/xx Date
    **************************************/
```

Is there any way that I can get this to be at the top of every new source file that I open in Dev-C++? I don't think a `header.h` file would work since it is only commented out.

Comment: you can always write a script to do this.

Comment: Bloodshed Dev-C++, or Orwell Dev-C++?

Comment: Bloodshed Dev-C++, wasn't even aware of Orwell Dev-C++

Answer (score 4):

There is a common feature of most operating systems called "copy/paste" that works between applications and lets you duplicate a block of text in one application in another.

Have a text editor open with a copy of the above.  Select it.  Do the copy command (usually a keyboard shortcut, sometimes a mouse one).  Move to the document you have created in Dev-C++.  Paste it.

Then, fill in the things that changed.

Unless you are doing more than a 100 of these, such a procedure will be faster than automating it.

Comment: While true, I guess OP knows all of this. That's why he's asking about Dev-C++: *"Is there any way that I can get this to be at the top of every new source file that I open in Dev-C++?"*

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know about "copy and paste", please read that I would like it to be automated.